# Can't send a basic, non MVC form using ajax in .Net (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, forms

I have seen answers to this question many times, but most of them are related to MVC controllers.

The issue I am having while trying to send a form using Ajax is that while in debug mode, the execution flow won't reach the break point I have in my code behind. Also, I notice that when I click in the submit button, the page refreshes very quickly; I though that the whole idea of ajax was to not refresh the page.

This is my index.aspx

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="ajaxform.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <fieldset class="fs1">

            <input id="inputData" tabindex="1" name="theinputData" class="field" placeholder="Paste URL, docId or docSetId" runat="server"/>
            <input id="form1Send" type="submit" class="button" onclick="submit()"/>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is the code of my ajaxform.js

```html
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
         
         var formData = new FormData(this);

         $.ajax({
             url: 'index.aspx/OnSubmit',
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: formData,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function (result) {
                 alert("We returned: " + result);
             },
             error: function (result) {
                 alert("Error");
             }
         });
         e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

Finally, here is my code behind

```
namespace mySpace
{
   public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }

       [WebMethod]
       public static string OnSubmit()
       {
           return "I was in code behind";
       }

   }
}
```

My break point is on the return line. Why the program never reach the WebMethod?

Comment: move `e.preventDefault();` to the top of the function. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. You're double declaring something to handle the form. Your `form1send` button has `onclick="submit()"` in it as well as the form submit handler you're wiring up via jQuery
2. The content of your JavaScript handler is slightly off, for example you set `contentType` twice.

Here's a simplified version of the JavaScript that *works on my machine*:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#form1').submit(function (e) {

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "index.aspx/OnSubmit",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: '{}',
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (response) {
                 alert(response.d);
             },
             failure: function (response) {
             }
         });
         e.preventDefault();
     });
});
```

NOTE: I based this (the content of the `$.ajax` call) on a code sample I found elsewhere, which is why the parameters and order of the parameters are different to yours.

If your app has a `RouteConfig.cs` file present, you may also need to change `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;` to `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;` if you see an HTTP 401 error in your browsers developer tools console for the request to your WebMethod decorated method in index.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

By executing `event.preventDefault()` before `FormData(this)` a premature refresh is prevented.
See below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#form1').submit(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var formData = new FormData(this);

         $.ajax({
             url: 'index.aspx/OnSubmit',
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: formData,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function (result) {
                 alert("We returned: " + result);
             },
             error: function (result) {
                 alert("Error");
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you have changed?

Comment: I moved the `event.preventDefault()` up before initialising the `FormData`.
This prevents page refresh. You were doing it after the ajax call which wouldn't work as the page would refresh which might cause the ajax call to terminate abruptly.